# Datagridviewcomboboxcolumn getting me mad

Tags: wpf, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

i have a wpf datagridview that is bound to a source
the source is a dataset filled from the database manually

there's a datagridcomboboxcolumn

i've set the column's items source to the dataset (DSGLAccounts.tables..etc),
set the displaymemberpath to the column name "Account_ID";

and it's successfully displays the account list 
but when i sellect an item at run time, the cell does not keep it when i navigates to another cell and just disappears

now i cannot understand how to make the sellected index equals some value depending on the dataset which is the source of the grid view (DSRegisters)

i need to know how to set the selected index
i think i have to know about the properties (SelectedItemBinding/SelectedValueBinding/SelectedValuePath)

Here's the form

[image: Snapshot from wpf form]
here's my stupid code :)

```
            <DataGrid Name="dgv_Accounts" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HeadersVisibility="Column" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                                          CanUserSortColumns="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                                          BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Gray" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Gray"
                                      AreRowDetailsFrozen="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" RowHeight="20" SelectionMode="Extended"
                                          FlowDirection="LeftToRight" GridLinesVisibility="All" UseLayoutRounding="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" 
                                          FontFamily="DFKai-SB" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Normal" Grid.Row="5" CellEditEnding="dgv_Accounts_CellEditEnding" RowEditEnding="dgv_Accounts_RowEditEnding">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="GL Account"  Width="*" >
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Transc_desc, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Debit" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Debit}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Credit" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Credit}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

that's code behind

```
            dgv_Accounts.ItemsSource = DSRegisters.Tables[0].DefaultView;


        DataGridComboBoxColumn COL = ((DataGridComboBoxColumn)(dgv_Accounts.Columns[0]));
        COL.ItemsSource = DSGLAccount.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        COL.DisplayMemberPath = "Account_ID";
```

where

DSRegister is a dataset contains records that should be displayed on the datagrid
DSGLAccounts is the dataset to which the datagridcombobox should be bound

also when i at run time as i said, when select a value from the combobox, it does not keep sellection when i leave the cell , as if it's non editable

i'm noooob in wpf, need help please , if there's an example or something like this , it would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Solution for keeping selected value - just add something like this in code behind:

```
COL.SelectedItemBinding = New Binding("SelectedItem");
```